# How to get ViewBag value to appear in the view

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have worked with Viewbags in the past and I was able to access the values on the cshtml side with no problems. This time around I can't seem to get the values to appear, I believe it might be the order of operations with rendering. Is there a way to enforce the viewbag to appear?

.cs

```
ViewBag.Title = "This is the Title"
```

.cshtml

```
<h1>@ViewBag.Title</h1>
```

When i check the source, I only see `<h1></h1>`

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Razor in your html file, like this?

```
@{

ViewBag.Title = "Artists";

}
```

This is my html file:

```
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Artists";
}

<h2>@ViewBag.Title</h2>
```

Comment: No I'm not. I don't think razor syntax works in a .cs file.

Comment: Sorry, i mean in your html file!

Comment: I am not doing that, I'm setting ViewBag.Title on the .cs (server side) no the client side (html).